# facebook like button script for off site not working in any of the options, HTML5, iframe, or other (XBML?)

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-like

I have tried all possibilities, all scripts possible, even created a flash object with the appropriate api link.  Nothing happens, nothing appears whatsoever when testing the page locally.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) show us your code 2) you can't *like* a local link

Comment: the code I WAS using is the code that's given when you click the "add like button to your website. Which is obviously dead wrong. 3 minutes after I submitted this question I found a link in Facebook Developers.. it actually works, unlike the others..

Comment: You can not use Facebook Social Plugins in Local Host, that i know of.

Comment: wasnt trying to "like" a local link, i was trying to add the script to like an actual page, just testing it locally, the script that i just found that DOES work is iframe also, but slightly different than what's given on the "get the code" for the like button   that code that does work following...  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>

Comment: Where did you get the faulty code form?

Comment: i typed "facebook like button code" in search on fb and got the "get the code page...   just tried that again 6 different times and hit submit and get thrown to the following url... more screwy stuff going on with FB.. ???????  http://likeaphobia.us/

Comment: I am done for the moment, got some security issues to change in my browser...  I dont like being "thrown" to another url without clicking on the link, point blank once that control is taken from me to chose, that to me becomes both aggressive and malicious.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  For me it was because I was placing it in a facebook app that was in sandbox mode.  To get around this be sure to have an fb:admins meta tag on your page. Even still if you've been surfing the url without the meta tag, facebook probably cached it, so you'll have to do some cache busting to test it out.